# How do I export an Oracle User-defined Type as a C# class in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, visual-studio

I know there is a way to convert an Oracle User-defined type (UDT) into a C# class using the VS Server Explorer. I believe you have to right-click on the UDT in the tree press 'Export as C# class' or something similar.

I have installed Oracle Developer Tools for VS 2015 & 2017, but when I connect to my Oracle database via VS Server Explorer, I cannot see the UDT folder in the tree. I can see Tables, Procedures & functions but not UDTs.

I've been struggling to figure out what I'm missing and any suggestions would be appreciate.

Comment: There no types there https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/building_odt.htm#TDPNG50020

Comment: Ha! Check this vid - now its there https://youtu.be/zrzDOk8gg5A?t=365   Could this be the user roles that have no access to types?

Answer (score 0):

Friend, this is possible yes but you must make the connection in Server Explorer using Oracle's 'Unmanaged Driver'.
With it the UDT will appear and when clicking with the right button will appear the option to generate C # class. Attention: this does not appear with Oracle's 'Managed Driver'.